# Vetur, type inference of deconstructed props has extra undefined type?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

With the following code, Vetur inferenced `x,y` to have type `number | undefined`.

The `undefined` cause tons of warning on further usage of `x,y` .

How can I remove the `undefined` from the type inference?

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: { x: Number, y: Number },
  setup(props) {
    let { x, y } = props
  },
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `props` are optional (as in it's possibly `undefined`) by default, so your `prop`s are typed as `number | undefined`.

You can declare the `prop`s as required using the long form of prop declaration, which removes `| undefined` from the `prop`'s type:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    x: {
      type: Number,
      required: true, //
    },
    y: {
      type: Number,
      required: true, //
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    let { x, y } = props
  },
})
</script>
```

[demo](https://tsplay.dev/N9yZJN)

As an aside, Vetur is deprecated, and [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnsoncodehk.volar) is the officially supported VS Code extension for Vue 3 and TypeScript, so consider switching.